# Regex to extract text from a paragraph

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have this text string

`key: "abc", value: "def"`

and I want to get only the text after `key:` -- so output should be `"abc"` inclusive of the quotes. How do I get this?

I've tried this but it does not work

`key: (.*),`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems to be correct but it may not work if you have, at the end. You need to make sure it matches first , after you start.

```
const regex = /key: (\"[^",]+\"),/gm;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('key: (\\"[^",]+\\"),', 'gm')

const str = `key: "abc", value: "def",`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

To parse/extract content from JSON best would be to use JSON.parse.

```
const data = JSON.parse('{key: "abc", value: "def"}');
console.log('"' + data.key + '"');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
\bkey\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*(?:,|$)
```

```js
const text = 'key: "abc", value: "def"';

const key = text.match(/\bkey\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*(?:,|$)/)?.[1];

console.log(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine matchAll() and groups:

```
let yourText = 'key: "abc", value: "def"' + ','  // extra comma for matching last element of your string

const result = [...yourText.matchAll(/[^:]+:\s([^,]+),/g)]
```

Result:

```
['key: "abc",', '"abc"', index: 0, input: 'key: "abc", value: "def",', groups: undefined]

 
[' value: "def",', '"def"', index: 11, input: 'key: "abc", value: "def",', groups: undefined]
```

- [^:]+ match everything that not contains :(colon), one or more times
- [^,]+ match everything that not contains ,(comma), one or more times